# Redirect Script that masks URL which points to a Heroku app

Tags: redirect, heroku, subdomain, rackspace

I have a static site hosted on Rackspace (e.g. example.com) with a subdomain (e.g. subdomain.example.com) that is using a redirect script to point a Heroku app. I would like to mask the Heroku app's URL and instead display the subdomain's URL.

Here is the redirect script I am using which is hosted at subdomain.example.com:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://example.herokuapp.com/railsapp/new");
?>
```

Is there anything I can do in the redirect script to mask the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day I'd say subdomain.example.com would use an iframe to load your Heroku app in -  that's by far the simplest option. The other option is more complicated to use a reverse proxy on subdomain.example.com to load the heroku content.